# Error while selecting rows in MySQL according to count criteria

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

I have a table in MySQL database from which I want to select a unique number of rows.My current table has 3 columns named user_id, image_id and is_like. I need to list all the
users for whom the count of user-id is equal to 221. For example, for a particular user 19, the count of 19 must be 221 in the column user_id. I have written the following code, but it gives me a wrong answer in the form:

```
SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE COUNT(userid)=221 GROUP BY userid
```

It gives me an error

> 1111 - Invalid use of group function.

Comment: What you want to achieve, your question is conflicting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM `votes` GROUP BY userid HAVING COUNT(userid) = 221
```

You need to use `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.

The `WHERE` clause filters which rows are selected. The rows are then grouped, then the numbers (in `userid` column) are the aggregated for the `COUNT` function.

`HAVING` is like `WHERE`, only it happens after the `COUNT` value has been calculated.

Comment: Grouping by userid will not give `COUNT(userid)`  as 221 at all. So your querry result will be null.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a HAVING clause. You can Google for that!